# Why does Bash reset PS4 value to its default value when starting a script?

Tags: bash

Here's a simple test script (named "testps")

```
#!/bin/bash
echo PS4=$PS4
```

and I have set and exported PS4 like this:

```
export PS4='$LINENO:'
```

When I run it, either with `./testps` or `bash ./testps`, the result is:

```
PS4=+
```

Looks like the value of "PS4" has been reset.

The only way I have found so far to customize `PS4` is to run the script with `bash -l` after having added `export PS4='$LINENO:'` in `.bashrc`.

What have I missed here?

Note also that when using `ksh`, PS4 is initialized with its value from the environment if any.

Comment: This happens _as root_, not otherwise. It's a recently-added security feature (I think late in the 4.x series, but that's spitballing -- would need to check the changelog).

Comment: What operating system are you using? `bash -l` starts a login shell and that normally doesn't read `~/.bashrc` at all. Some Linux distros explicitly source it, but not that many.

Comment: You _can_ use `BASH_ENV` to force bash to source a config file at script startup.

Comment: ...the very short form "why?" is that folks can use a malicious PS4 to cause the shell to run arbitrary commands.

Comment: (I'm not sure there was a good reason for this change -- an attacker who can set arbitrary environment variables can perform arbitrary code execution plenty of other ways, but... _shrug_)

Comment: Responding to several questions above:
* Yes I'm running as root (the script require this, forgot to check that sorry)
* OS is RHEL 8.3
* it works when using BASH_ENV , why no security issue in that case then ?

Comment: It _is_ just as much a security issue in the BASH_ENV case, but POSIX requires shells to honor `ENV` during startup, so `BASH_ENV` (used by bash instead of the POSIX-specified name when not in compatibility mode because too many people abuse `ENV` for other things, not realizing that it's meaningful to the shell) is offering a surface that POSIX sh requires to exist. As I said, I don't agree that this was worth "fixing", so please don't ask me to defend the decision.

Comment: ...the _political power_ arguing for it to be fixed probably stemmed from the existence of [CVE-2016-7543](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2016-7543/). Once there's a CVE, it's easier to just apply a technical fix to make it go away than it is to argue that it should never have been accepted.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior doesn't happen with all users -- a copy of `PS4` from the environment is only ignored when running as root, since shell version 4.4.

Quoting from [`CHANGES`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/a99d905216cc0aac5de0c3050f4afc54e21c6bc5/CHANGES#L2333-L2334) in the bash source:

> g.  Shells running as root no longer inherit PS4 from the environment, closing a security hole involving PS4 expansion performing command substitution.

This was done because environment variables are passed to setuid executables, and some setuid executables (unwisely) use `system()`, `popen()`, etc. to invoke a shell. While ld.so ignores `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_PRELOAD` and similar when running in setuid, bash historically did not do so with environment variables that could cause arbitrary execution.

As described in https://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2016/09/26/9, this issue could be exploited as follows:

```
env -i SHELLOPTS=xtrace PS4='$(id)' ./test
```

...would run `id`, instead of printing `$(id)` as part of xtrace logs, even if invocation of `./test` crosses a privilege boundary.

---

Personally, I set PS4 *inside* my scripts -- it's ignored unless they're run with `set -x`, after all, so why *not* establish a meaningful value regardless?

If you want to force it to happen with fewer side effects than you get from `bash -l` or `bash -i`, set `BASH_ENV` to have the name of a file that can be sourced to perform your desired initialization.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the release notes. I've made others replies to other comment too

Comment: @GillesPion, ...I've followed up to add details on the security issue at hand. To be clear, I do consider _any_ setuid executable invoking a shell without completely overwriting the set of environment variables unforgivable on its own, and a bug in that executable rather than in the shell, but... here we are.

Comment: @GillesPion, ...bash _does_ have an argument intended to make it safe to invoke in a setuid shell, btw (disabling `ENV` / `BASH_ENV` / `SHELLOPTS` / exported functions / etc); this is `-p`. `system()`, `popen()`, &c don't use it, though -- understandably, since it's a bash extension and they invoke `sh`.

Comment: this "-p" switch exists also in ksh and have apparently the same purpose